# Python doesn't find modules from dist-packages

Tags: python, linux, debian

Debian, Python 2.7

I've installed a module, but Python doesn't see it, and IPython does. Investigation has shown that all external modules are installed in `\usr\local\lib\python2.7\dist-packages`.

#### Python's sys.path

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 11 2015, 09:39:24)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

#### IPython's

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import sys; print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions', '/root/.ipython']
```

How can I fix that?

Now I see, I have two Python 2.7 installations. How do I fix it? Would it help if I uninstall one of them? How to do it?

How do I make `pip` install packages for 2.7.10?

Comment: @AnandSKumar and what if I have several pythons?

Comment: I just noticed that they have different python version. How is it possible?

Comment: *How did you install ipython?*

Comment: @AnandSKumar dunno. Either with pip or apt-get

Comment: Did you install python separately (Maybe a newer version or so) ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I think from sources (2.7.10). Dunno where 2.7.3 comes from. Could it be installed with ipython?

Comment: No, I believe it was found by default. You installed a python on top of it.

Comment: @AnandSKumar It's possible too.